# Error in c++: "terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::length_error' what(): basic_string::_M_replace_aux"

Tags: c++, string, floating-point

I have a simple function that takes a string of digits and turns them into a floating-point number, the function is underneath:

```
float convertStrToFloatNumber (std::string n) {
    // Converts the number n to a float in the form of 000.000
    if (6 - n.length() > 0) {
        // The representation is with trailing zeros
        n.append(6 - n.length(), '0');
    }
    // Insert . at the 3. spot
    n.insert(3, ".");
    return strtof((n).c_str(), 0);
}
```

How ever i throws the following exception when run with the input `"030000"`:

"terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::length_error' what(): basic_string_M_repalce_aux"
what im really interested in is understanding what the last part of the error means.

Comment: Can you give us enough code to replicate the error? I constructed a `main` that I thought would replicate the error but it ran perfectly fine.

Comment: Sure give me a second, it's apparent of a bigger source file (a G-code parser)

Comment: isn't length in number of characters?

Comment: @MartinSigNørbjerg The length is an unsigned integer, and the result wraps around to its maximum value when you "pass through" zero.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz the code is uploaded to a github repo: https://github.com/Collatz124/GC-TSM

Comment: @molbdnilo so I just have to convert it to a signed int then? forgive me I'm new to c++

Comment: @MartinSigNørbjerg Questions here should be *self contained* and in [mcve] form. *Not* rely on stuff behind external links (like GitHub).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `n.length()` is unsigned, `6` is promoted to the same unsigned type, and when the length is greater than six the subtraction will wrap around and produce a huge positive number.

The most robust (and shortest) solution is to avoid the subtraction completely;

```
if (n.length() < 6)
{
    n.resize(6, '0');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The issue does not occur for `"030000"`, but for any string longer than 6 characters.

`std::string::length()` returns unsigned type. Due to integral promotion rules, `6` gets promoted to unsigned type and you perform subtraction on unsigned types. Underflow on unsigned types result in wraparound, so `0 - 1u` is equal to `std::numeric_limits<unsigned>::max()` (if `unsigned` is 32-bit, then it's equal to `2^32 - 1` = `4294967295`)

---

You can simply change the logic of condition:

```
if (n.length() < 6)
```

Or cast the `length` to signed type:

```
if (6 - static_cast<int>(n.length()) > 0)
```